# Can Director::forceWWW() and Director::forceSSL() be used together in SilverStripe?

Tags: https, silverstripe

I have a SilverStripe website which I'd like to always use the `www` domain prefix and always use `https`.

So:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

Would all redirect to:

```
https://www.example.com
```

However when I put the following lines in `/app/_config.php`:

```
Director::forceWWW();
Director::forceSSL();
```

I get a redirect loop. The same thing happens if I swap the order:

```
Director::forceSSL();
Director::forceWWW();
```

Does this mean that `Director::forceWWW()` and `Director::forceSSL()` can't be used together?

What configuration should I use to get my desired outcome?

Comment: While I also prefer to use `.htaccess`, this sounds like a bug to me and you should report it on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are correct in that `forceWWW()` and `forceSSL()` can't be used together.

If our site is on an Apache server we can add redirect rules to our root `.htaccess` file to do these two redirects:

```
# ...

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect non www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect non https to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # ...
```

Comment: +1. This is also better for SEO if you're using multiple domains that point to the same website (eg. `example.com` and `example.org`) because the rewrite will force a single domain.